# Method to extract a phase between input and output of a nonlinear system

Tags: phase, non-linear

I have a nonlinear (blackbox) system which gets a singular frequency (f) signal as input:

```
input = A*sin(2*pi*f) + B
```

And I get an output signal, which has oscillations + unknown trend that looks like this:

[image]

My question is what would be the best way to extract the phase between the two signals? Are there specific methods for extraction of phase in nonlinear systems?
In the case of detrending the output, is there a robust method to do it that ensures not altering the phase while detrending?

I hope this is the right place for this question, if not I will take it somewhere else.

Comment: Does it make any sense to ask about phase difference if the system is non-linear? If given a sinusoidal input of frequency $\omega$, some non-linear systems will give an output of frequency $n \omega$.  Do you know something about the non-linearity that leads you to assume the output will have the same frequency content as the input?

Comment: I do know that the output will carry the same dominant frequency f (plus noise coming from the trend), and I'm looking for the phase of that frequency f. It makes sense because I want to compare the phases between different outputs when changing the amplitude of the input.

Comment: Could phase cancellation work in this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the system will pass through the same dominant frequency, if you I/Q sample both the input and the output centered on that frequency, you can compute the phase for both the input and the output. Then, you can subtract the input phase from the output phase, or vice versa, to get a phase difference.